# Adding currency in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle database and I have these 2 tables:

- `Space` (id_space (PK), zone, type(FK))
- `Offer` (id_space (FK), sell, price, currency)

I need to find the minimum and the maximum price for the spaces in each zone, and I have spaces with different currency, and i need some help where should i include that to make possible to compare and find the lowest of eg.100 EUR and 100 USD.
The type that I need is "11" and the and the sell needs to be 'N'.

The currency can have values: 'EUR','USD', and a simple conversion is ok like 1EUR=1.11USD

Here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT s.zone, MIN(o.price),MAX(o.price)
FROM Offer o JOIN Space s ON s.id_space=o.id_space
WHERE s.type=11 AND o.sell='N'
GROUP BY   s.zone
```

And this is the output

```
+------+--------------+--------------+
| Zone | MIN(o.price) | MAX(o.price) |
+------+--------------+--------------+
| 1    | 80           |          478 |
+------+--------------+--------------+
| 2    | 100          |          100 |
+------+--------------+--------------+
| 3    | 100          |          150 |
+------+--------------+--------------+
```

But there in the last row, the 100 is EUR and the 150 is USD, and i have a 140 EUR witch is more than 150 USD.  Have anyone some idea?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as text tables.  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Group by currency too. You can't aggregate amounts in different currencies, so calculating the overall MIN/MAX is pointless

Comment: Besides, *no* conversion has actual meaning without the *time* it refers to and even the XR source. The exchange rate today won't be the same as the XR tomorrow. Banks change the XR daily, airlines modify their XRs weekly, and brokers change it throughout the day. If you wanted to convert the amounts to one currency you'd need a table with XRs per day

Comment: Even Google, the probable source for that XR, uses a different rate for its fligh ticket sales simply because airlines and GDSs change their rates weekly, not daily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expressions to determine the exchange factor according to the currency.

For example, if you result should be in €, assuming you only have the two currencies € and $:

```
SELECT s.zone,
       min(o.price
           * CASE o.currency
               WHEN 'EUR' THEN
                 1
               WHEN 'USD' THEN
                 .9
             END),
       max(o.price
           * CASE o.currency
               WHEN 'EUR' THEN
                 1
               WHEN 'USD' THEN
                 .9
             END)
       FROM offer o
            INNER JOIN space s
                       ON s.id_space = o.id_space
       WHERE s.type = 11
             AND o.sell = 'N'
       GROUP BY s.zone;
```

Comment: Assuming a fixed exchange rate is impractical. Even for a single day. I'd bet (actually I know) that *Google's* flight tickets use different XR than the one returned by the site, simply because airlines and GDSs change their XRs weekly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That depends on the use case. For a stock exchange like application yes, that won't work. For a lot of "normal" uses, e.g. small businesses who sell in the EU and US, yes it would. They don't even change the rate daily but rather have a fixed rate until the rate changes so drastically for a longer period, that a correction is deemed necessary.

Comment: Even then, the XR should be in a separate table so people don't have to change all their reporting queries and risk leaving some of them unchanged

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That's not a bad idea, indeed. But the OP doesn't seem to have such a table and as I read the post they're explicitly happy with a fixed rate ("a simple conversion is ok like 1EUR=1.11USD").

Comment: yes, its ok a fixed rate, i need it for a university project so it wont be any more practical. Thank you

Comment: @RolyGr *especially* in this case, using a table gets more points. You can expect a question "what if the rate changes"?

Answer (score 1):

Exchange rates change and if you want to avoid modifying every reporting query every time the rate changes, you'll have to store the rate in a table.

The easiest way to do that would be to have an ExchangeRates table with rates between the stored currency and your "base" currency. Assuming the base currency is USD :

```
Create Table ExchangeRates(Currency char(3),Rate decimal(5,3));
Insert into ExchangeRates(Currency,Rate)
Values
('USD',1)  -- The base currency
('EUR',1.11),
('GBP',1.32),
('INR',0.014) -- XRs don't have just two decimals
```

The query only needs a join to the XR table:

```
SELECT s.zone, 
    MIN(o.price*xr.Rate),
    MAX(o.price*xr.Rate)
FROM Offer o JOIN Space s ON s.id_space=o.id_space
INNER JOIN ExchangeRates xr on o.Currency=xr.Currency
WHERE s.type=11 AND o.sell='N'
GROUP BY   s.zone
```

Comment: Okey, that eventually will save some codeing, thank you for your time.